# Multiple queries in one php script

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to send data entered in a single form to multiple tables using multiple queries but it is not working. I have the connection thing working right and this way it works fine for one query but the problem comes when I try to use multiple tables, like getting data and sending it to multiple tables
What I have done so far is:

```
$qry= "INSERT INTO register VALUES (DEFAULT, '".$email."', '".$passw."')";
$qry = "INSERT INTO personalinformation VALUES (DEFAULT, '".$name."', 
'".$fname."', '".$age."', '".$gender."', '".$cnic."', 
'".$mobileno."','".$address."', '".$appearencestatus."')";
```

Kindly help.
Thank you so much

Comment: Do you have a database conncetion? or are just forming the strings?

Comment: Defining the query string (`$qry = "...";`) is not enough. You need to execute it.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: It works fine for one query but doesnot run for the second

Comment: and yes I have the database connection

Answer (score 0):

With PDO you'd do something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO register (email, password) VALUES (:email, passw)";
$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email))
```

Once for each query. It's important to *always* specify the columns you're inserting against, it avoids ambiguity when your schema changes for some reason plus the crufty `DEFAULT` junk in there.

Try to prepare *directly* from a string, don't make intermediate variables for this sort of stuff. Those can easily get confused, over-written, and tangled up in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Did you create a database connection? And did you execute the query with mysqli_query ? Try troubleshooting by echoing out the composed query, and copy pasting it in mysql console or in php myadmin.

Here is a sample:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
```

Your queries composition code: Then

```
mysqli_query($con, $queryvariablename);
```

--

P.S make sure you use different variable names for different queries or else the second one will overrite the previous one.

Comment: Yes I have the the connection thing written, it works fine for one query but I just need to know that how I am supposed to write it this way for tqo queries.

Comment: It is same as getting form data by post and thn sendinf it to multiple tables rather than one.